# Unable to properly free malloc of another malloc

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

Here's the snippet with issues.

```
int main()
{
    char** RESERV = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*4);
    printf("%i, %i, %i, %i, %i", **RESERV, *RESERV, RESERV, &**RESERV, sizeof(char*));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        RESERV[i] = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char),16);
        RESERV[i][15] = '\0';
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        RESERV[i]="Iambananananananananananana";
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("\r\n>%i<", RESERV[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\r\n<%i>", (RESERV[i]));
        free(RESERV[i]);
    }
    free(RESERV);
}
```

This code `free()` is working fine in 32 bit , but somehow crashes horribly in 64 bit mode.

In my main program I've omitted freeing the members of the `char**` causing unexptected behavior every now and then, which I obviously do not want.

I've tried playing around with addresses and pointers, even tried

```
free(RESERV+(i*sizeof(char*))
```

Which failed too. Can someone clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Let's start with what you're trying to achieve, looks like you're trying to allocate a two dimensional array - the equivalent of char[4][16]. is that correct?

Comment: Well, this is kind of the small form, a more average example is more like char[300][150]. But overall yes, 2d char array.

Comment: This does not create a 2D array, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117161/why-do-i-need-to-use-type-to-point-to-type).

Comment: Oh my, I guess I messed up quite a bit more than I thought.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings. Don't ignore them! Try to fix them, instead of ignoring.

Comment: There are no compiler warnings, I'd wish there were any. I can't stand warnings.
I tried Lundin's link but I get weird behavior with printf if I print %s loop this. -Snip-
Code looks awful if I paste it here.
It's pretty much the same code, but with the initialisation replaced with the help from Lundin's link. I allocate 15 f's and add a '\0' at the end, but I get 27, 23, 19 and 15 f's with the last one being correct.

Comment: "*There are no compiler warnings*" -- Really? If so, you have to increase the warning level of your compiler. Include warning flags. If GCC, include the `-Wall` and maybe `-Wextra` flags.

Comment: Flags are set and I still don't get any warnings. I'm using DevCPP with the TDM-GCC 32/64 bit debug mode.

Comment: What?? It will sent warnings. `printf("%i, %i, %i, %i, %i", **RESERV, *RESERV, RESERV, &**RESERV, sizeof(char*));` has many problems. And did you use `strncpy`? That would give weird results when printing using `%s`. If so, NUL-terminate *after* calling `strncpy`

Comment: I do not use strncpy, I for loop 16 times, the first 15 times allocating an f and allocating '\0' at the end. I do not use strncpy as I read a lot of data from large files and need to do "stuff" with them ( remove, add, move, etc. ). I seriously do not get any warnings.
Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0

Comment: I cannot understand what is wrong. If you need help, i'll have to see the code. Post a new question including the relevant parts of the code and I will be happy to help you.

Comment: I'd rather not as I don't want to appear spammy with questions, but I don't have much of a choice if I want to properly show my code.

Comment: Oh well, I can't post for another half an hour, perhaps I can elaborate if I'm not clear enough?

Comment: I probably interpret the post wrong, or the post is wrong. Y=X and X=Y, I threw it in the debugger and it told me one string in the malloced 2d array was 4 members long with Y = 4 & X = 16. Yeah the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
 RESERV[i]="Iambananananananananananana";
```

creates the problem. It *overwrites* the memory allocated by `malloc()`. Thus,

1. You face memory leak, because the `malloc()`ed pointer is *lost*.
2. You cannot call `free()` with the changed pointer. It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:**

In `C`, you don't assign *strings*, instead, you can use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to get your work done.

Notes:

1. even in case of `strcpy()` you cannot use `"Iambananananananananananana"`. In this case, it will create memory overrun as destination does not have enough memory to hold it completely.
2. Use proper format specifiers. in your `printf()` statements, most of the arguments to `%i` are not of type `int`. For pointer type arguments, you should be using `%p`, atleast. Otherwise, it will be UB.

Comment: I'm wondering why 32 bit doesn't care?

Comment: @Nos it's not about 32 bit or 64 bit, it's about [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Nos Well, if it _worked_, I'll consider ___bad luck___. :-)

Comment: Alright, while we're on string copying anyways, while copying chars one for one is another correct way of doing it?

Comment: @Nos yeah, tha'll be ok, because, you'll be copying values in that case. :-)

Comment: I suggest mentioning about other things that cause UB. OP has used `%i` but arguments don't match `int*`, which `%i` expects.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks Updated, and I believe you meant `int`, not `int *`, right?

Comment: Yes. I meant to say `int`, not `int*`. Got mixed up when thinking about `%p` and stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
RESERV[i]="Iambananananananananananana";
```

This is not the proper way to populate this string after allocating it.  You are overwriting the value of that pointer.

```
strncpy(RESERV[i], "Iambananananananananananana", 15);
RESERV[i][15] = 0;
```

This is what you're looking for.

Notice, too, that you are apparently to assign something into that pointer that is larger than the memory that you have allocated.

Comment: I wrote a larger string to see if it'd overflow to the other members, but I confess about the string allocation part.

Comment: Experimentation is good. ;)  I saw that you were printing out the pointer values.  Personally, I find them much more meaningful in hex (%x) rather than decimal.

Comment: This will cause more problems as `strncpy` does not NUL-terminate `RESERV[i]`

Comment: @CoolGuy Ah, you're right.  I should have caught that in this case or used an `snprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 RESERV[i]="Iambananananananananananana";
```

is incorrect - You need to do

```
 strncpy(RESERV[i], "Iambananananananananananana", 15);
 RESERVp[i][15] = 0;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause more problems as  `strncpy` does not NUL-terminate `RESERV[i]`?

Comment: @CoolGuy - Good point - edited answer