# Number of elements in pointer to structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, vector, struct

I haven't coded in C for at least a year and am trying to brush up on it with writing a very basic software for calibration. Basically I have a `PointCloud` struct

```
typedef struct {
    gsl_vector ** vectors;
    gsl_vector * mean;
} PointCloud;
```

`vectors` points to an array of `gsl_vectors` and `mean` is just a `gsl_vector` representing the mean of the vectors in `vectors`.

Now suppose I have a variable `PointCloud * foo` and assume its internal variables have memory allocated dynamically using `malloc()` and are populated. Let `bar = foo -> vectors`. How can I get the number of `gsl_vectors` in `bar` (i.e the number of vectors in the point cloud)? I have tried various combinations such as `sizeof(bar)/sizeof(bar[0])`but that gives me the output 1. `sizeof(bar)` in itself gives me the value 8. I have tried this on a point cloud with 27 vectors.

Comment: There is no way to determine the number of entries in `vectors` at compile time, which is what calculations involving `sizeof` would require. You must have some way of knowing how many entries are in `vectors`. If you don't then... well, how can you not?

Comment: Thanks for that useful info. And yeah don't worry I know how many there are I was just too lazy to give it its own variable in the struct.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question.

Comment: "I was just too lazy to give it its own variable in the struct." But why not? It's simple, easy and a lot clearer.

Comment: You should declare vectors as a pointer to array then, not pointer to pointer, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117161/why-do-i-need-to-use-type-to-point-to-type).

Comment: Carey, the was question was basically can I use `sizeof` to determine the number of vectors. That was it. I did not know about the compile time feature of `sizeof`. If I had known I would have stuck with having a size variable and would not have asked the quetion. Like I said, I haven't done C code in a while. Lundin, thank you for your link it was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sizeof`  operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) is a compile-time operator. When applied to some pointer, it gives the size of pointers on your machine (on my x86-64/Linux system it is 8 bytes), and since it is computed at compile time it does not depend at the run-time size of the dynamically allocated heap memory zone.

**You need to keep somewhere the size of any dynamically `malloc`-ed array** or zone. You might consider ending your `struct` with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and keeping its size as a previous member of that `struct`