# Can you return a type of pointer to pointer in a function?

Tags: c, pointers

I know you can return a type of pointer from a function.
ex. `void *foo()`
Can you return a type of pointer to pointer in a function?
ex. `void **foo2()`

Here is more info about my question:

I try to assign a ptr-to-ptr, tmp2, to blocks[i][j], and then return tmp2.  blocks[i][j] is a ptr-to-ptr as well.

I'm confused to manipulate a ptr to a ptr-to-ptr: I am not sure if `return ((tmp2+i)+j);` is the cause of the segmentation fault at line `printf("2---%d\n", **tmpPtr2);`.  To debug, I try to print: `printf("%d\n", *( (*(tmp2+i)) +j) );`  However, it causes a new segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **blocks, **tmp2;
int n = 10;

int **findBlock2(int b){
    int i, j ;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            if (blocks[i][j]==b){
                printf("%d\n", blocks[i][j]);

                //Segmentation fault
                printf("%d\n", *((*(tmp2+i))+j) );

                return ((tmp2+i)+j);
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    int **tmpPtr2;

    //allocate memory space and assign a block to each index
    blocks=malloc(n * sizeof *blocks);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        blocks[i]=malloc(n * sizeof(*blocks[i]));
        blocks[i][0]=i;
    }

    if ((tmpPtr2=findBlock2(4))==NULL)    return -1;

    //Segmentation Fault
    printf("2---%d\n", **tmpPtr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Update to answer my question:

(1) Adding t`tmp2=blocks;` to the top of findBlock2() removed both segfaults.

(2) `return ((tmp2+i)+j);` shows how to manipulate a ptr-to-ptr pointing to a ptr-to-ptr or a 2D array

(3) `printf("%d\n", *( (*(tmp2+i)) +j) );` shows how to do (2) and dereference it.

Hope it helps others

Comment: Do you actually mean a pointer to a pointer OF a function? or are the given answers what you want?

Comment: The answer is yes, but you probably have a related coding problem that you are trying to solve with it, so publish your code and the specific problem, and you'll get a much better answer than just Yes + a couple of examples which are most likely not relevant to your problem.

Comment: You two are right, let me update my question.  :)

Comment: Use `[ ]` notation instead of `*((*((s)+(y))+1)` or whatever, it is much easier to read

Comment: You get a segfault because you never point `tmp2` anywhere, but you dereference it inside `findBlock2`

Comment: Also, im pretty sure `((tmp2+i)+j)` is like saying `(tmp2+i+j)`

Comment: You probably want a 2D array instead of this [pointer-to-pointer heap fragmentation mess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30117625/584518). It is really alarming how very few C programmers there are who know how to allocate 2D arrays dynamically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just like you would with any pointer variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ** function(){
    int ** matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*));
    *matrix = malloc(sizeof(int));
    matrix[0][0] = 5;
    return matrix;
}

int main()
{
    int **matrix = function();
    printf("%d",matrix[0][0]);
    free(matrix[0]);
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Adding to the other part. In your function `findBlock2` besides accessing an invalid reference that has already been pointed out, it seems that your objective is to return a reference to the block that fulfills `if` statement. If that is the case then returning a pointer to `int*` should suffice.

`int *findBlock2( int b )`

```
/////////////////
```

`return ( *(blocks+i)+j );`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a 2D array at not some slow, fragmented lookup table. In that case, do like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void* alloc_2D (size_t x, size_t y)
{
  return malloc (sizeof (int[x][y]));
}

int main (void)
{
  const size_t X = 5;
  const size_t Y = 3;

  int (*arr_2D)[Y] = alloc_2D(X, Y); 

 // X dimension was omitted in declaration to make array syntax more intuititve:

  arr_2D[i][j] = something;

  ...
  free(arr_2D);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes". Please refer the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void ** foo2(void){
    int **p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    return (void**)p;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%p\n", foo2());
    return 0;
}
```

The result is (in my `32-bit` platform):

```
0x80e9008
```

Comment: `return (void**)p` is non-portable; `void**` is not a generic pointer type like `void*` is. It should just return `void*`, and then the calling code could cast it to `int **` before dereferencing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: "`return (void**)p is non-portable`", could you give some examples? I really don't know this issue, thanks very much!

Comment: `int *` and `void *` might have different size and representation  (on modern systems they don't, but I have used one where it did), so pretending that a pointer points to a `void *` when it actually points to an `int *` will not retrieve a sensible pointer