# Create 2D array by passing pointer to function in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, malloc

So I read dozens of examples of passing an 2D array pointer to function to get/change values of that array in function. But is it possible to create (allocate memory) inside the function. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void createArr(int** arrPtr, int x, int y);

int main() {

    int x, y;       //Dimension
    int i, j;       //Loop indexes
    int** arr;      //2D array pointer
    arr = NULL;
    x=3;
    y=4;

    createArr(arr, x, y);

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            printf("%d\n", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    _getch();    
}

void createArr(int** arrPtr, int x, int y) {
    int i, j;       //Loop indexes
    arrPtr = malloc(x*sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        arrPtr[i] = malloc(y*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            arrPtr[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: There are no array pointers in your code, nor any 2D arrays.

Comment: @Martin 
Could you tell me how?

Comment: @Lundin
Ok so there is pointer to pointer to int, but it can be used in as a pointer to 2Dim array, right?

Comment: @Marcin No, it cannot. It's a common mistake, you've been learning from bad sources. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, passing a pointer to `int **` (but 3 stars is considered bad style), I suggest to return an allocated variable from your function:

```
int **createArr(int x, int y)
{
    int **arrPtr;
    int i, j;       //Loop indexes

    arrPtr = malloc(x*sizeof(int*));
    if (arrPtr == NULL) { /* always check the return of malloc */
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        arrPtr[i] = malloc(y*sizeof(int));
        if (arrPtr[i] == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            arrPtr[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
    return arrPtr;   
}
```

Call it using:

```
arr = createArr(x, y);
```

Comment: You should check all return values of `malloc`, not only the first one.

Comment: There is no reason to create a segmented pointer-to-pointer thing. Instead, when you want a 2D array, use a 2D array.

Comment: Soo.. I can do it like this:
void createArr(int*** arrPtr, int x, int y);
And here arrPtr is a pointer which point to a **int, which can contain addresses for arrays. But it looks bad.

And another way ,more elegant, is the one you showed. Thank you very much for quick answers!

Comment: @Marcin It looks bad because it is bad. You shouldn't use any pointer-to-pointer to begin with. You should use real 2D arrays, assuming 2D arrays is what you want.

Comment: @Lundin
But I have to create this array dynamically (don't know the dimension before runtime), so I have to do it like this.

Comment: Consider for example: `void crash_and_burn (void) { int** wannabe_array = createArr(5, 3); int** wannabe2 = createArr(5, 3); memcpy(wannabe2, wannabe_array, sizeof(int[5][3])); }`

Comment: @Marcin No, see my example. VLAs (and more importantly pointers to VLAs) have been in C since the year 1999.

Comment: This may appear to work as a 2D array when using `[i][j]` access method but it is not the same as `int arr[x][y]`

Comment: @4386427 No it may never work like a 2D array. Arrays are allocated in adjacent, contiguous memory. Just because you use the `[ ]` operator on a pointer, the pointer doesn't magically turn into an array. Run my "crash_and_burn" example above, for example. Disclaimer: it might cause your computer to crash and burn, since pointers are not arrays.

Comment: @Lundin - That was actually what I tried to say in my comment. Since everything is ok as long accesses are done using `[i][j]`one migth considered it to be the same as `int arr[x][y]` but it isn't.

Comment: @Lundin
To sum up all the information:
1) I don't really get why my version (void createArr(int** arrPtr, int x, int y)) didn't work. Assuming that want to allocate array like this, because I'm stupid why it doesn't work. I pass the pointer, so why it's work in main function, but not in my function. If I will understand this, I promise I will allocate 2D arrays like this:
int (*array)[y] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );
2) Your crash_and_burn() example won't work because we start to copy the memory from  arr* (so not the data, but some random memory space)?

Comment: @Marcin It won't work for the same reason as why `void func (int x) { x=5; }` won't change any variables in the caller. You didn't attempt a plain variable though, you attempted to allocate a pointer to an array of pointers. Yet your pointer to an array of pointers was only changed locally inside the function, like `x` in my example.

Comment: @Marcin The crash and burn example will crash and burn because it used a pointer to an array of pointers instead of a real 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about pointer-to-pointers. They have nothing to do with 2D arrays.

How to do it correctly: [How do I correctly set up, access, and free a multidimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c).

One of many reasons why it is wrong to use pointer-to-pointer: [Why do I need to use type** to point to type*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117161/why-do-i-need-to-use-type-to-point-to-type).

Example of how you could do it properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void* create_2D_array (size_t x, size_t y)
{
  int (*array)[y] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );

  for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i) 
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < y; ++j) 
    {
      array[i][j] = (int)(i + j);
    }
  }

  return array;
}

void print_2D_array (size_t x, size_t y, int array[x][y])
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i) 
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < y; ++j) 
    {
      printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}


int main (void)
{
  size_t x = 5;
  size_t y = 3;

  int (*arr_2D)[y];

  arr_2D = create_2D_array(x, y);

  print_2D_array(x, y, arr_2D);

  free(arr_2D);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I try to use your version it say that :
size_t y expression must have constant value. So you can't make arrays like this dynamically (as I said...)

Comment: @Marcin I did compile and test this code. You must use a compiler made after the year 1999 (why wouldn't you?). For example GCC. You can tell GCC to be a C compiler with the compiler options `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: I spent whole day today and can't figure out one think. Everything from your example seams to work but I can't figure out this. If I print table by function `print2DArray(xDim, yDim, arr);` I get all elements so it works fine. If I print one element like this `printf( "%d\n", arr[0][0])` it is fine to. BUT if I print like this `printf( "%d\n",old[1][1]);` or any other value different than 0, I get segmentation fault. Please help me.

Comment: @Marcin What is "old"?

Comment: Sorry. "old" is the name of array that I use in my code, but here i pasted it as `arr`. So it should be  `printf( "%d\n",arr[1][1])`. The names are fine in code.

Comment: @Marcin Well, then something in the code is wrong :) Please post a separate question.

Comment: Here is the link to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782015/2d-array-pointer-access-segmentation-fault-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an array can be initialized this way. As long as you pass a pointer, the memory address should remain the same. So, if you assign anything to the pointer it will valid.

Think of an a[] as a* pointer to the first element

a [][] will be a** pointer to a pointer of the first element or a pointer to the first array (first row of a table)