# Malloc usage in c inside a function

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a pointer to a function.In this function  i use malloc to reserve space.The problem is that when i return in main the program doesn't respond.Here is my symplified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int def(char **B){
    int i;
    B = malloc(3 * sizeof( char ));
    for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        B[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        scanf("%s" , B[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        printf("%s\n" , B[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **B;
    int i;
    def(B);
    for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        printf("%s\n" , B[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent the code;

Comment: You need to call free() on the pointer when you are done with it.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. If you have to hard-code the dimensions use `#define` so that every usage refers to a single definition. That way, it won't be so easy to allocate memory for fewer elements than there should be: and the code will be easily maintainable. And, do you realise you can only enter a 4-character string in the `scanf` statement, which is unrestricted.

Answer (score 2):

```
int def(char **B)
```

should have been

```
char** def(char **B)
```

and its return value should have been

```
return B; 
 /* else the memory allocated inside the function will be freed at
  * the end and by accessing it later you have undefined behavior for the 
  * rest of the program
  */
```

```
B = malloc(3 * sizeof( char ));
```

should have been

```
B = malloc(3 * sizeof( char*)); // you have two levels of indirection. so char* first
```

```
for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) // similary with the other for loops
```

should have been

```
 for(i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) // you used 3 in the above step
```

```
def(B);
```

should have been

```
B=def(B);
```

It is a good practice to use `free()` to free the allocated memory though it will be automatically freed at the end of the program

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.  All this does is allocate a bunch of memory which is lost when the function returns.

Comment: @TomKarzes : Didn't noticed that in the beg. but fixed it now

Comment: `B=def(B);` - really? Passing `B`makes no sense. Further since you take the effort of writing a good answer, please also mention that malloc can fail, i.e. test the return value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to malloc something that looks like a 2D array (or rather an array of strings).

However,

```
def(B);
```

is a call by value so `B` doesn't change when the function returns.

If you want to change `B`you need

```
def(&B);
```

and then you need to change the function signature accordingly - then you'll be a three star programmer.

If you want to do this correct then read:

[Create 2D array by passing pointer to function in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744561/create-2d-array-by-passing-pointer-to-function-in-c/36744785#comment61072139_36744785)

and read the answer given by @Lundin - that's the way to do it

Comment: Then the types are wrong.  This is an very incomplete answer.

Comment: @TomKarzes - exactly, that is step 2 of the problems with this code

Comment: Introducing a third level of indirection instead `return` the pointer from function to `main`.

Comment: @ameyCU - Agree - but that is not how the code from OP is structured. I made my answer in the intend of keeping OPs original structure.

Comment: @4386427 OP doesn't use its function even correctly . His function returns `int` but he never use that values . So , this should be taken care of (_as I don't think OP understands what he exactly wants_).  And for record I did not down vote  :)

Comment: @ameyCU - Again, agree. There are so many things to fix in this code. The purpose of my answer was/is to tell OP that he/she can't change `B` in that way and what he/she must do instead. I do not intend to rewrite the whole code to show how it should be done. I guess you don't agree with my approach. That's OK.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to allocate a list of strings, but you do not provide the ability to reference this outside the `def` function. Part 1 of your problem is that you need to be providing a pointer to your list:

```
int def(char ***B) {
```

Another option is to return the pointer you have created:

```
char** def() {
```

Secondly in your first malloc you allocate space for 3 `chars` but you need `char` pointers. `sizeof char != sizeof char*`.

```
B = malloc(3 * sizeof( char ));
```

Should be:

```
*B = malloc(3 * sizeof char*);
```

Also you should use `const int` or `#define` to define your size constants so you dont accidentally get the wrong size in different places, eg.

```
#define SIZE_OF_LIST 3
int def(char ***B){
    int i;
    B = malloc(SIZE_OF_LIST * sizeof( char ));
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_LIST ; i++){
```

Finally when you pass your pointer to the function `def` you need to do this (top accommodate the first change):

```
def(&B);
```

or

```
B = def();
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.  All this does is allocate a bunch of memory which is lost when the function returns.

Comment: @TomKarzes I realized this just before you commented, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is worse than that.  All C function arguments are 'by value', meaning that the variables inside the function are local copies of the variables passed in at the call.  So when you assign a value to an argument (which you are allowed to do, unless it is declared 'const' *[I assume C++ 'const' has been adopted in C by now]*), you are NOT assigning to the variable passed in at the call.  So in this case the statement

```
B = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
```

does NOT alter the pointer **B** declared in **main()**; it just leaks memory.  Assuming you really need to return an **int** for this function, you need to add a level of indirection:

```
int def(char ***B){
    *B = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        (*B)[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    }
    ...
}

...

char **B;
...
def( &B );   /* Note the 'address-of' operator! */
```

If the return doesn't have to be **int**: eliminate the argument to **def()**, change it to return ****char**, return the result of the first **malloc()** directly, and change the call to **B = def();**

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that when you call `def(B)`, you are creating a `char **` that is a **copy** of `B`. If you change this new `B`, the changes doesn't reflect on the main function, since they were made to the copy of `B`.

You should use a `char ***` and call `def(&B)` (i do not consider this a good approach, tho) or you could have `B` initialized at the main and call `def(B)` to alloc and read its `char *` or you could return the new `B`.

Also, check the problems pointed in other answers.